# C++ pointer weird undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

Compiling with -O2 (or -O3 for that matter) and running this program yields interesting results on my machine.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Pointer to an int in the heap with a value of 5
    int *p = new int(5);
    // Deallocate the memory, but keep a dangling pointer
    delete p;
    // Write 123 to deallocated space
    *p = 123;
    // Allocate a long int in the heap
    long *x = new long(456);

    // Print values and pointers
    cout << "*p: " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*x: " << *x << endl;
    cout << "p:  " << p << endl;
    cout << "x:  " << x << endl;

    cout << endl << "Changing nothing" << endl << endl;

    // Print again without changing anything
    cout << "*p: " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*x: " << *x << endl;
    cout << "p:  " << p << endl;
    cout << "x:  " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

g++ -O2 code.cc; ./a.out

```
*p: 123
*x: 456
p:  0x112f010
x:  0x112f010

Changing nothing

*p: 456
*x: 456
p:  0x112f010
x:  0x112f010
```

What I am doing is writing to a deallocated `int` in the heap pointed to by `p` and then allocating a long with address `x`. My compiler consistently places the long on the same address as `p` -> `x == p`.
Now when I dereference `p` and print it, it retains a value of 123, even though it has been rewritten with the long 456. `*x` is then printed as 456. What is even weirder, is that later, without changing anything, printing the same values yields the expected results. I thought this was an optimization technique which only initializes *x when it is used after printing the value `*p`, which would explain it. However, an objdump says something else. Here is a truncated and commented `objdump -d a.out`:

```
00000000004008a0 <main>:
  4008a0:   41 54                   push   %r12
  4008a2:   55                      push   %rbp

Most likely the int allocation, where 0x4 is the size (4 bytes)
  4008a3:   bf 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%edi
  4008a8:   53                      push   %rbx
  4008a9:   e8 e2 ff ff ff          callq  400890 <_Znwm@plt>

I have no idea what is going on here, but the pointer p is in 2 registers. Let's call the other one q.
q = p;
  4008ae:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx

  4008b1:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi

*p = 5;
  4008b4:   c7 00 05 00 00 00       movl   $0x5,(%rax)

delete p;
  4008ba:   e8 51 ff ff ff          callq  400810 <_ZdlPv@plt>

*q = 123;
  4008bf:   c7 03 7b 00 00 00       movl   $0x7b,(%rbx)

The long allocation and some other stuff (?). (8 bytes)
  4008c5:   bf 08 00 00 00          mov    $0x8,%edi
  4008ca:   e8 c1 ff ff ff          callq  400890 <_Znwm@plt>
  4008cf:   44 8b 23                mov    (%rbx),%r12d
  4008d2:   be e4 0b 40 00          mov    $0x400be4,%esi
  4008d7:   bf c0 12 60 00          mov    $0x6012c0,%edi

Initialization of the long before the printing
*p = 456;
  4008dc:   48 c7 00 c8 01 00 00    movq   $0x1c8,(%rax)

  4008e3:   48 89 c5                mov    %rax,%rbp

The printing
  4008e6:   e8 85 ff ff ff          callq  400870 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
........
```

Now, although `*p` has been overwritten by the `long` initialization (`4008dc`), it is still printed as 123.

I hope I made any sense here, and thank you for any help.

to make myself clear:
**I am trying to figure out what is going on behind the scenes, what the compiler does, and why the resulting compiled code does not correspond with the output. I KNOW THIS IS UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR AND THAT ANYTHING CAN HAPPEN. But that means that the compiler can produce any code and not that the CPU is going to make up instructions. Any ideas are welcome.**

PS: Don't worry, I am not planning to use this anywhere ;)

EDIT: On my friend's machine (OS X) it yields the expected results even with optimization.

Comment: You are trying to make sense of undefined behavior. Enjoy the process.

Comment: Is there a question I missed? Also... "[...] *it yields the expected results*" hehe good one =).

Comment: @luk32 Oh, right :D I didn't state a question. I am just trying to figure out what is going to behind the scenes. So far, it is not making any sense. :D

Comment: @DietmarKühl I very well realize that, but reading the actual compiled code still does not explain it. (which it should)

Comment: @sammko I would strongly suggest bolding out, that you seek help understanding assembler, or whatever you seek for. Otherwise, people will just say it's UB and it doesn't need to make sense and shrug it off, and they are completely right. Focusing that something is weird is focusing on obvious. Thus, posting a clear question is vital to avoid getting ridiculed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I thought about that too, but it works in an analogous way if I fill both variables with values that span all of their bytes.

Comment: Have you seen this, which might be useful for exploring this kind of thing: http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @tillaert Undefined behaviour means that the compiler can produce any code, not that the CPU can make up instructions. See the attached objdump.

Comment: With modern processors that use multiple cores, pipelining and multi-level  caching you can't know when real memory will be updated especially with optimizations unless the behaviour is defined to guarantee it.

Comment: `weird undefined behavior` is an oxymoron!!!

Comment: @JCx wow, finally something useful. Thanks, I have not seen that. I will look into it some more.

Comment: You are asking us to tell you what happens (predictably) when you do something that is undefined behavior.  In fact, what you are seeing has nothing to do with the compiler and everything to do with the memory management library.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer And I suppose that's why the behaviour can be explained perfectly just from a disassmebly of my compiled executable? See the accepted answer.

Comment: @RSahu Yes that's what I am doing. And with help from Michael Burr, it is what I have done. It was quite fun, to be honest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stopped looking at your disassembly output too soon (or at least you didn't post the next few lines, which are relevant to your question). They probably look something like:

```
movl    %r12d, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSolsEi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
```

`rbx` and `r12` are registers that must be preserved across function calls in the x64 ABI used by GCC on Linux.  After the allocation of the `long`, you see this instruction:

```
mov    (%rbx),%r12d
```

The uses of `rbx` earlier in the instruction stream include:

```
mov    %rax,%rbx       ; store the `p` pointer in `rbx`

...

movl   $0x7b,(%rbx)    ; store 123 where `p` pointed (even though it has been freed before)

... 

mov    (%rbx),%r12d    ; read that value - 123 - back and into `r12`
```

then you see in the snippet I posted above, which is the disassemble that didn't make it into your question and corresponds to part of the `cout << "*p: " << *p << endl` statement:

```
movl    %r12d, %esi    ; put 123 into `esi`, which is used to pass an argument to a function call
```

And `123` gets printed.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that is exactly what caused it. Thank you very much for an useful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, this might be due to the optimizations enforced by the compiler. If you compile with -O0, then, it will be printing 456 for the values. As p was deleted and x was immediately allocated, x will be pointing to the same address  that p was pointing (may not be the same case always, but in your tests that is the case most probably). Hence, *p and *x should have de-referenced to same value. 
If you change the order of print statements, then always 456 will get printed for the values. I have changed the order of first two cout statements in your code as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Pointer to an int in the heap with a value of 5
    int *p = new int(5);
    // Deallocate the memory, but keep a dangling pointer
    delete p;
    // Write 123 to deallocated space
    *p = 123;
    // Allocate a long int in the heap
    long *x = new long(456);

    // Print values and pointers
    cout << "*x: " << *x << endl;
    cout << "*p: " << *p << endl;
    cout << "p:  " << p << endl;
    cout << "x:  " << x << endl;

    cout << endl << "Changing nothing" << endl << endl;

    // Print again without changing anything
    cout << "*p: " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*x: " << *x << endl;
    cout << "p:  " << p << endl;
    cout << "x:  " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I observed this too, and if `*x` was initialized only when it was used it would make sense. However as is seen in the objdump, it is initialized to 456 before printing `*p`

Comment: SO users have this weird (and undefined) tendency of down-voting any question that doubts the existence of the holy UB, takes the name of the Lord thy goddess of UB in vain, or bears false witness against her holiness queen UB 2.0. I have up-voted it in order to compensate, since OP is obviously and innocently not aware of the fact that he or she should **not** post UB questions on this website, or else, bare the wrath of the community.

Comment: @barakmanos Yeah this, from an unknown reason seems to be precisely the case. Thanks for the upvote, and any curious questions about UB I may have in the future, will be asked somewhere else. I have learnt my lesson.

Comment: @sammko: You're welcome. BTW, "learnt" and "behaviour" make it very obvious as to where you're from :)

Comment: @barakmanos Ha! You may think that I am from the UK, but English is actually not my first language. I just use the British alternatives. :P Gotcha! If you are curious, I am from Slovakia.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to find the answer in your own source code or what the compiler does to it, even if you produced assembly output from the compiler.

The undefined-ness is happening the C-runtime memory allocator, which is already compiled binary code that's linked against your test application. When you call new, the runtime library decides where the pointer goes. There's no guarantee that new/delete/new will mean the second new gives you the same address, it's completely implementation dependent.

If you REALLY want to know, then you need to build with full source code including the source code for new, and then read how it's implemented and/or step through it in a debugger to see what's going on.